# how to create a array of hashes in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I am trying to make this behavior with my custom toastr notification

this is what i have

```
  def toast(type, text)
   flash[:toastr] = { type => text }
  end
```

I call this in my controller like this

```
toast('success',"this is a message")
```

and it would output to my template like so

```
        <% flash[:toastr].each do |type, message| %>
            toastr.<%= type %>('<%= message %>')
        <% end %>
```

however it only outputs 1 message

now here is the functionality I am trying to make, which is display multiple flash messages 
http://tomdallimore.com/blog/extending-flash-message-functionality-in-rails/

it works because of the following  method

```
def flash_message type, text
  flash[type] ||= []
  flash[type] << text
end
```

everytime you call `#flash_message`, it would save the flash message in an array, and I can use `for each` on the array to display it.

I am having trouble converting my `#toast` into that, `#toast` CURRENTLY does this

```
flash[:toastr] = {'success' => "this is a message"}
```

I would like to do this

```
flash[:toastr] = [{'success' => "this is a message'},{'error' => "problem!"}]
```

Can someone help me modify `toast` method to accept an array of hashes, and inserts a new hash everytime its called?

Answer (score 1):

```
def toast(type, text)
  flash[:toastr] ||= []
  flash[:toastr] << { type => text }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array#push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-push):

```
def toast type, text
  flash[:toastr] ||= []
  flash[:toastr].push({ type => text })
end
```

Using append ([`<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C)):

```
def toast type, text
  flash[:toastr] ||= []
  flash[:toastr] << { type => text }
end
```